# $x^4-14x^2+24x-k=0$ has $4$ real and unequal roots, what is the range of $k$?

Tags: polynomials

$x^4-14x^2+24x-k=0$ has $4$ real and unequal roots, then $k$ lies between $11$ and $117$ or $-11$ and $-8$ or $8$ and $11$ or $0$ and $8$

How can you find the range of $k$. It's an entrance exam question so the solution should not be too long

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried.

Comment: Saw a similar question here where they found Maxima and minima and then found the range, but I didnt exactly get the answer so I posted mine.

Comment: FInding maxima and minima should be useful. What are the maxima and minima you found?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^4-14x^2+24x-k$.  Then $f'(x)=4(x-1)(x-2)(x+3)$ so to have four unequal real roots of $f$ you want $k$ such that
$$
f(-3)<0, f(1)>0 \text{ and } f(2)<0.
$$
Since $f(-3)=-117-k$, $f(1)=11-k$, and $f(2)=8-k$, you get the answer $8<k<11$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but how did you choose 8<k<11 in the last step?

Comment: Impose all three constraints $f(-3)<0$, $f(1)>0$, $f(2)<0$.

Comment: @user10354138 somehow the constraint you mentioned doesnt seem to be immediately obvious to me. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0):

*A sketch*:

I would put it in a different way: rewrite the equation as $\;x^4-14x^2+24x=k$, and set
$$g(x)=x^4-14x^2+24x.$$
Now $g'(x)=4(x^3-7x+6)$ has three roots: $-3, 1,2$, so that the  quartic $g(x)$ has one local maximum at $1$ and two local minima, at $-3$ and $2$. Furthermore, it tends to $+\infty$ when $x\to\pm\infty$.

We  conclude that the equation $g(x)=k$ has four distinct roots if and only if $k\in \bigl[\max\bigl(g(-3),g(2)\bigr), g(1)\bigr]$.